# effect similar to infinite scroll for javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, infinite-scroll

I want to achieve something similar to infinite scroll, but I want it to trigger when an element is in the viewable window rather than scroll position. Any ideas?

Comment: none of them yet. But from what I understand of all of them they are bassed of the widow height or scrollbar position, not weather something is visible or not. I'm kinda looking like something bertween inifinate scroll and lazyload I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few little static helper functions in a Utils class for occassions such as these:

```
Utils = {
    underView: function(element) {
    return (($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop()) <= element.offset().top);
},

aboveView: function(element) {
    return ($(window).scrollTop() >= element.offset().top + element.height());
},

inView: function(element) {
    return (Utils.aboveView(element) !== true && Utils.underView(element, element.height()) !== true);
}
```

};

Implemented thusly:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(Utils.inView($(".div"))){
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: seems close. How do you get something like this to run in the background so the user doesn't have to manually trigger it?

Comment: @David: add it to the `load`, `resize` and `scroll` event of the window.

Comment: Just edited the implementation to show it within the scroll event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery's offset() to see if an element is on screen or not:

http://api.jquery.com/offset/